# Making ecommerce website issue with session

Tags: php, jsp

I using two sessions one for add to cart and one for the user.
But when i add any product to cart it remain in the cart for all the users. So let me know how can a particular user has it own product in his cart and doesn't show the same product for all the users.

Here is the code for add to cart link

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
 $query = query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id=" . escape_string($_GET['add']). " ");
 confirm($query);
    while($row = fetch_array($query)){
        if($row['product_quantity'] !=$_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']]){
            $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']]+=1;
               redirect("cart.php");
        }

    }

}
```

and code for showing product in cart

```
foreach($_SESSION as $name =>$value){
        if($value > 0){
                    if(substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_"){

                        $length = strlen($name) - 8;
                        $id = substr($name, 8 );
    $query = query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($id) . " " );
    confirm($query);
```

Comment: `I using two sessions one for add to cart and one for the user.` how it is possible? are you using different session cookies?

Comment: When they login write some code 'like this'  ` $_SESSION['user_id'] =$user['username'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time(); ` This is if you aren't already doing it, from the code above it doesn't seem like you are

Comment: first , common session for cart and one for the login which is if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
 $user_email=  $_POST['user_email']; 
 $password=  $_POST['user_password'];
    
    escape_string($user_email);
         escape_string($password);
    
   $query = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '{$user_email}' AND user_password = '{$password }' ");
confirm($query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
set_message("Your Password or Username are wrong");
redirect("signin.php");


} else {$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;
redirect("my-account.php");

     } }